# Rails Openshift Hot Deploy assets not served

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openshift, assets, hotdeploy

i have a Rails application deployed on Openshift. I added marker for hot deploing and hot deploying itself works fine, but during the time application is hot deployed css and js files are not served. When hot deployment ends these files work fine again. I also use Bootstrap and Sass in this application (gem 'bootstrap-sass'). Do you have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue, and it works now. I will explain what I did, maybe it will help somebody.

Basically there is need to precompile your assets locally, and commit and push them. This is done by
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

But there is a gotcha!!! Locally precompiled assets doesn't match those that are generated on Openshift. How is this possible? There is a bug on Openshift, that assets are generated on production with RAILS_ENV=development :/ More info here:
https://github.com/openshift/origin-community-cartridges/issues/8
so there is need to add environmental variable on your application:
rhc set-env RAILS_ENV=production -a app_name
then generated assets match.

So after fixing it, when during changes to assets, we need to precompile them again. And to make them work during hot deploying there is need to have both old precompiled assets and new precompiled assets in repo. For example:
If you have old file:
application-10770925dc8abd4ceab34119af4032163cc5a94f3523d60d321f33a999171d58.css
and new precoimpiled file:
application-82f6fca47056cbda52cb32086051f031b880e2630a137f0e41e96cb2eef923ee.css
they both have to be in repository. During hot deploying old asset is still referenced, so it has to be in repository. After hot deploying ends, new asset is referenced. In the next commit and push old asset may be removed.
So basically this issue is fixed for me, and hot deploying works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The files are being served by Apache via the Passenger module.  The files are being replaced "in place" which causes them to be removed/rebuilt, which is causing them to not be served during that time, and since they are static assets, they are not stored in memory.  Unfortunately there is currently no way to make hot deploy work fully with Rails to keep the site 100% working while it is deployed.

Comment: Could changing Apache to Nginx, or changing Passenger to Puma/Unicorn/Thin help with this issue?

Comment: Yes, but you would have to do it in a custom or DIY cartridge.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have your assets in a separate running project, since there is no easy way to have them available as all times as @developercorey explains..

It's probably not the best solution, but would be a simple patch-solution which is not tightly coupled to one particular hosting platform.